# Adjust minted code inside Minipage environment

Tags: indentation, minipage, minted

I'm trying to show an equation on one side and its algortihm on the other. I tried using  two minipages (one for equations and the other for algorithms) but it doesn't look beautiful; howerver, with the following code it works well  except for the horizontal space appearing on the last two line as you can see on the picture. How can I fix that ?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\usemintedstyle{tango}
\usepackage{extarrows}

\begin{document}
\section{Codage du PID}
On précise que l'angle à réguler va être celui de l'axe \textbf{X} qui est parallèle à la tige. Pour le régulateur \textbf{PID} on utilise les commandes temporelle mentionnées dans la partie théorique.\\[5mm]
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
$\mathbf{\mathlarger{u(t)=K_P * e(t)}} $ \hspace{7.1mm} $\xrightarrow{\makebox[1cm]{code}}$
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{minted}[bgcolor=black!4]{c}
proportionnel=Kp*erreur 
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.36\textwidth}
$\mathbf{\mathlarger{\noindent u(t)=K_I *\int{e(t)dt}}}$ \hspace{1.9mm} $\xrightarrow{\makebox[1cm]{code}}$
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}
\begin{minted}[bgcolor=black!4]{c}
integral=integral_précédent+erreur*temps_écoulé
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.36\textwidth}
$\mathbf{\mathlarger{\noindent u(t)=K_D\frac{de(t)}{dt}}}$ \hspace{6.8mm} $\xrightarrow{\makebox[1cm]{code}}$
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.63\textwidth}
\begin{minted}[bgcolor=black!4]{c}
dérivé=(erreur-erreur_précédente)/temps_écoulé
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `\mintinline` and an alignment.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\usemintedstyle{tango}
\usepackage{extarrows}

\begin{document}

\section{Codage du PID}

On précise que l'angle à réguler va être celui de l'axe $X$ qui est 
parallèle à la tige. Pour le régulateur \textbf{PID} on utilise les commandes 
temporelle mentionnées dans la partie théorique.
\begin{alignat*}{2}
u(t)&=K_P e(t) && \xrightarrow{\text{\quad code\quad}}
\mintinline[bgcolor=black!4]{c}{proportionnel=Kp*erreur}
\\
u(t)&=K_I \int e(t)\,dt && \xrightarrow{\text{\quad code\quad}}
\mintinline[bgcolor=black!4]{c}{integral=integral_précédent+erreur*temps_écoulé}
\\
u(t)&=K_D\frac{de(t)}{dt} && \xrightarrow{\text{\quad code\quad}}
\mintinline[bgcolor=black!4]{c}{dérivé=(erreur-erreur_précédente)/temps_écoulé}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

I removed all `\mathbf` declarations. It's anyway not the right way to embolden symbols.

[image]

Comment: It’s perfect. Just curious about the proper way to embolden symbols ?! @egreg